# Derivation of Fick's first law for discrete spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

The questions are created using a translator. 
Fick's first law for discrete spaces was explained in the book about biomathematics.

$$
J = -D (C_{i+1} - C_i)
$$

In considering the derivation of this equation, I decided to follow the method of deriving Fick's law in continuous space.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvrhY.png)

$N$ : Number of particles, $S$ : cross-sectional area.
I attempted to derive the equation based on the number of particles passing through the red filter per unit time and unit area as shown in the figure.

1. $J = - \frac{1}{2S\Delta t} (N_{i+1} - N_i)$
2. $J = - \frac{(\Delta x)^2}{2\Delta t} \frac{1}{\Delta x} (\frac{N_{i+1}}{S \Delta x} - \frac{N_i}{S \Delta x})$
3. $J = -D \frac{C_{i+1} - C_i}{\Delta x}$

$C$ : Volume density. 
In the third equation, I want to eliminate $\Delta x$ and derive $J = -D (C_{i+1} - C_i)$. What should I do?

Comment: Hint: $\Delta x=(i+1)-i$.

Comment: Oh!!! Thank you very much!!! Your nice idea solved the problem!!